# SAPUI5 ODataModel attachRequestCompleted function is getting called twice automatically

Tags: sapui5

```
oModelDetailData.attachRequestCompleted(function()
{
    var rowsCount =oModelDetailData.oData.getElementsByTagName("Row").length;
    oPassedFields=["C_INCIDENT_DATE_TIME","R_INCIDENT_DATE_TIME"];
    debugger;
    console.log(oModelDetailData);
    console.log(oPassedFields);
    updateTZ(oModelDetailData, oPassedFields, plantCode)
    debugger;
    console.log(oModelDetailData);
    oTableDetailData.setModel(oModelDetailData);
    oTableDetailData.bindRows({path: "/Rowset/Row/"});
    sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.hide();
});
```

How i can prevent oModelDetailData.attachRequestCompleted function to execute automatically twice , i used debugger everywhere in my code but i could not find anything, due to this the updateTZ() also gets called twice.

Answer (score 3):

Is the countMode of your model set to "Request" maybe? This mode triggers a second separate request.
You can try to set it to "Inline" so data and count are in the same request.
Alternatively you can detach your request completed event as soon as your callback is triggered.

EDIT

You can also use the attachEventOnce(sEventId, oData?, fnFunction, oListener?) method. You can find more info in the API reference [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.EventProvider%23methods/attachEventOnce)